# Plot propagates MachinePrecision numbers despite `WorkingPrecision`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

**Edit** solved, `Plot` calls candidate function using MachinePrecision for its argument, hence need to use `SetPrecision` to recover original precision.

FindRoot seems to use suboptimal method by default, for the problem below, Newton's method converges in <10 iterations, but `FindRoot` requires >100, is there a way to get `FindRoot` to use Newton's (or an easy drop-in replacement for `FindRoot`)?

```
asymp1[p_] := (f[x_] = 
    Log[2 Zeta[2 p] HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], p]^2] - 
     Log[Zeta[p]^2 HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], 2 p]];
   df[x_] = D[f[x], x];
   x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxIterations -> 100, 
     Jacobian -> {{df[x]}}]);
approx = -EulerGamma + Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]/(-1 + p);
Plot[{asymp1[p], approx}, {p, 1 + 1/100, 1 + 1/10}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotLegends -> {"true", approx}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}]
```

Comment: Why `First[x]`? It gives me an error. If I replace it by `x`, I get a reasonable looking plot.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That plot is low accuracy however, the red should match dashed line

Answer (score 6):

*Summary*

The principal problem seems to be loss of precision in `f[x]` and `df[x]` when `p` has finite precision.  Note that the first workaround works because passes infinite-precision values for `p`; I did not appreciate why exactly it worked when I posted it. There is also some internal numerical bug, which prevents a complete analysis of the problem.  I suspect it has to do with one of the special functions, but I see no easy way to track it down.

---

There seems to be a precision issue with `Plot`.  Newton's method is already being used by `FindRoot`, albeit with step control, which is normally advisable and has a minimal effect when a problem is rapidly convergent.  `FindRoot` in `asymp1[]` works fine outside of `Plot`.

```
asymp1[p_] := (f[x_] = 
    Log[2 Zeta[2 p] HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], p]^2] - 
     Log[Zeta[p]^2 HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], 2 p]];
   df[x_] = D[f[x], x];
   x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxIterations -> 100, 
     Jacobian -> {{df[x]}}]);

approx = -EulerGamma + Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]/(-1 + p);
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@
  Table[N@{{p, asymp1[p]}, {p, approx}}, {p, 1 + 1/100, 1 + 1/10, 
    1/1000}], PlotLegends -> {"true", approx}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Black, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

---

Here's a workaround for `Plot` and verification of the OP's claim about the number iterations needed:

```
asymp1 // ClearAll;
asymp1[p0_?NumericQ] :=
  With[{p = SetPrecision[p0, Infinity]},
   (f[x_] = 
     Log[2 Zeta[2 p] HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], p]^2] - 
      Log[Zeta[p]^2 HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], 2 p]];
    df[x_] = D[f[x], x];
    x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 10},
      WorkingPrecision -> 20,
      PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10,
      MaxIterations -> 10, Jacobian -> {{df[x]}}])
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem seems to be the loss of precision when `p` is injected into `f` and `df`.

---

*Analysis of precision in OP's original code*

There are a couple of modifications: I `NumericQ`-protect `asymp1[]` and some code to log the evaluations of `asymp[]`.

```
asymp1 // ClearAll;
log = {}; (* data log for analysis *)
asymp1[p_?NumericQ] :=
  (f[x_] = 
    Log[2 Zeta[2 p] HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], p]^2] - 
     Log[Zeta[p]^2 HarmonicNumber[Exp[x], 2 p]];
   df[x_] = D[f[x], x];
   log = {<|"p" -> p, "precf" -> Precision[f[x]], 
      "precdf" -> Precision[df[x]]|>, log};
   x /. FindRoot[f[x], {x, 10},
     Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None},
     WorkingPrecision -> 20,
     PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
     MaxIterations -> 100, Jacobian -> {{df[x]}}]);
approx = -EulerGamma + Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]/(-1 + p);
Plot[{asymp1[p], approx}, {p, 1 + 1/100, 1 + 1/10}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotLegends -> {"true", approx}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}}]
```

> FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function `(Log[3.25314 HarmonicNumber[E^x,1.01]^2]-Log[10112.2 HarmonicNumber[E^x,2.02]])` is less than WorkingPrecision (20.`).

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

[image]

Collect the data:

```
ds = Dataset[Flatten@log];
```

Input precisions: The numbers occur in reverse order from last evaluation to first evaluation.  `Plot` for internal reasons makes to test evaluation, one at the input precision (`Infinity` in this case) and one at machine precision. I believe these results are analyzed and discarded. Then we have 146 evaluations at precision 20, which are used to construct the plot.

```
ds[All, #p -> Precision[#p] &] // Normal // Short[#, 5] &
(*
{1.0999691089381486986 -> 20.,
 1.0220719253114549652 -> 20., 
 1.0219517094650325539 -> 20., <<143>>,
 1.01 -> MachinePrecision,
 101/100 -> \[Infinity]}
*)
```

Here are the precisions of `f[x]` and its derivative `df[x]`.  They have from 1.5 to 2.5+ digits less precision.  These function are used to calculate the Newton steps by `FindRoot`.  For reasons I did not explore, this causes trouble at the low end of the interval for `r`.

```
ds[;; -3][Transpose, {"precf", "precdf"}] // 
   KeyValueMap[Histogram[#2, PlotLabel -> #1] &] // 
  Normal // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Oddly enough, executing the infinite-precision workaround for `Plot`, corrects some internal numerical problem that remains a mystery.  Executing the infinite-precision workaround makes the previously posted workaround and its variant work beautifully.  (See the edit history for the code.)

Comment: I tried with fresh kernel, and neither of these recipes appear to work in latest Mathematica -- [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-findroot-plot-precision.nb)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Try it now.  It seems that the code I updated with just now cause the code I posted earlier to work.  I don't know why.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It works on WolframCloud, too. Please check and confirm for me, if you could.  Thanks.

Comment: yup, the new code works. TLDR; Plot[f(x)] gives f(x) machine precision numbers regardless of WorkingPrecision, hence need to manually upgrade precision by using `SetPrecision` command

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov `Plot` make just one machine-precision test of `f[x]` (usu. the left end point of the plot interval) before beginning to plot at working precision 20. It doesn't use the value for plotting, as far as I can tell. I don't believe it is connected to the problem here.