# How to avoid underflow in Plot?

Tags: plotting

Any tips how to make the following plot show something?

Replacing it with `Plot` appears to work, but I need log-log scale

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = (-10001 + 51 E^9900 + 50 E^10000)/(5000 E^10000);
x0 = 1/100;
tmin = 10;
tmax = 1/x0^2;
LogLogPlot[a t^-1, {t, tmin*100, tmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `Simplify` to your quotient of two very large numbers:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = Simplify[(-10001 + 51 E^9900 + 50 E^10000)/(5000 E^10000)];
```

This turns $a$ into `(50 - 10001/E^10000 + 51/E^100)/5000`, which Mathematica evaluates to be a little bit more than `0.01`:

```
x0 = 1/100;
tmin = 10;
tmax = 1/x0^2;
LogLogPlot[a t^-1, {t, tmin*100, tmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000]
```

[image]

This does still throw some underflow errors, due to the fact that it's a "little bit more than 2" (specifically, about one part in $e^{-100}$ bigger.)

Alternately, you can use Mathematica's arbitrary-precision arithmetic capabilities to define `a` to be accurate to very high precision.  In particular, in your case the difference between $50 e^{10000} + 51e^{9900}$ and $50 e^{10000} + 51e^{9900} - 10001$ is in the 4340th digit or so:

```
N[Log[10, 51 E^9900 + 50 E^10000] - Log[10, (10001)]]
(* 4340.64 *)
```

So if we define `a` to be accurate to 5000 decimal places, the accuracy will probably be sufficient:

```
a = N[(-10001 + 51 E^9900 + 50 E^10000)/(5000 E^10000), 5000]
(* Rest of code as before, with same results and no warnings *)
```

Comment: Interesting, so I it looks like the lesson here is that I need to convert expression to specific precision before feeding it into `Plot`, using `WorkingPrecision` option is insufficient. Similar thing applies to `FindRoot` as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285648/plot-propagates-machineprecision-numbers-despite-workingprecision)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with your constant 'a'.  The exponents could not be represented within a normalized machine number.  You need to apply arbitrary machine numbers:

```
a = (-10001 + 51*Exp[N[9900, $MachinePrecision]] + 
50*Exp[N[10000, $MachinePrecision]])/(5000*
Exp[N[10000, $MachinePrecision]])
```

a=0.0100000000000

[image]

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid using machine precision here. In this case it works but I have seen Plot give misleading picture by using machine precision as you suggest

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - `N[#, $MachinePrecision]&` is **arbitrary-precision**, not machine recision. Compare `N[1/3, $MachinePrecision]` with `N[1/3, MachinePrecision]` `$MachinePrecision` is a numeric constant.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = (-10001 + 51 E^9900 + 50 E^10000)/(5000 E^10000);
x0 = 1/100;
tmin = 10;
tmax = 1/x0^2;
Show[
 LogLogPlot[a t^-1, {t, tmin*100, tmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This works, too, strangely enough:

```
Pane@LogLogPlot[a t^-1, {t, tmin*100, tmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 1000]
```

It suggests to me a weird bug. Maybe you should report it to WRI.

Note: Machine underflow happens and creates messages, but it doesn't really affect the plot.

---

Addendum: The output of some trials of the code below show that only machine precision numbers are used, despite `WorkingPrecision -> 100`. This leads to an empty output:

```
f[t_Real] := Quiet[Sow@t; a t^-1];
LogLogPlot[f[t], {t, tmin*100, tmax},
 WorkingPrecision -> 100]; // Reap
(*
{Null, {{1000.05, 1048.16, 1098.59, 1151.45, 1206.85, 1264.91, 
   1325.77, 1389.56, 1456.42, 1526.49, 1599.93, 1676.91, 1757.59, 
   1842.16, 1930.79, 2023.68, 2121.05, 2223.1, 2330.06, 2442.17, 
   2559.67, 2682.82, 2811.9, 2947.19, 3088.99, 3237.61, 3393.38, 
   3556.65, 3727.77, 3907.12, 4095.11, 4292.14, 4498.64, 4715.09, 
   4941.95, 5179.72, 5428.93, 5690.13, 5963.9, 6250.85, 6551.59, 
   6866.81, 7197.2, 7543.47, 7906.42, 8286.82, 8685.52, 9103.41, 
   9541.4, 10000.}}}
*)
```

All the evaluations lead to underflow.
Running it again (sometimes -- hardly ever, in fact) show 100-digit numbers fed to `f[t]` as well as machine precision equivalents (large image of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnX1p.jpg). This leads to the expected output.

Here's a strange workaround. It seems to give consistently the right plot:

```
f // ClearAll;
f[t_Real?Developer`MachineRealQ] := t; (* or whatever *)
f[t_Real] := a t^-1;
LogLogPlot[f[t], {t, tmin*100, tmax},
 WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

I guess the problem is that `LogLogPlot` gives an empty plot for a function that evaluates to a constant `0.`, which makes sense.  But that does not explain why it ignores working precision for such a crucial decision.

Comment: Okay, retesting I get inconsistent results from trial to trial...definitely a bug.

Comment: Another bug along these lines, it appears impossible to make this work `Plot[x, {x, 1, 1 + 10^-13}]`, came up in this [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298177/how-to-plot-in-a-tiny-interval-avoiding-must-have-distinct-machine-precision-n/298179?noredirect=1#comment736630_298179)