# How to stop`Plot` from using normalized machine numbers?

Tags: plotting

The following generates underflow  `Exp[-15372.9] too small to represent as a normalized machine number` warnings:

```
Plot[E^(-14 E^7 + 2 logh) (1 + E^7)^(2 + 2 E^7) (1 - E^logh)^(2 E^7), {logh, -10, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
```

Earlier [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286999/how-to-avoid-underflow-in-plot) for this issue is to convert some numbers into fixed precision numbers. But this doesn't appear to work here, is there a simple workaround?

```
N[Exp[-15373], 10] (* works fine *)
N[Exp[-15373]]  (* underflow *)
```

Comment: how about turning the check off? `SetSystemOptions["CheckMachineUnderflow"->False];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = E^(-14 E^7 + 2 logh) (1 + E^7)^(2 + 2 E^7) (1 - E^logh)^(2 E^7);

expr2 = Exp[Log[expr1] // FullSimplify[#, logh ∈ Reals] &]

(* E^(2 (-7 E^7 + logh + (1 + E^7) Log[1 + E^7])) (1 - E^logh)^(2 E^7) *)

expr1 == expr2 // FullSimplify[#, logh ∈ Reals] &

(* True *)

Plot[expr2, {logh, -10, 0}]
```

[image]