# How to Plot in a tiny interval, avoiding "must have distinct machine-precision numerical values" error?

Tags: plotting, numerics

**Edit** even simpler example which appears impossible to make work:
`Plot[x, {x, 1, 1 + 10^-13}]`

---

The following code fails with `` "Endpoints for x in \ {x,4.9999990463256835937`6.999999917164892,5.0000009536743164063`7.\ 000000082835091} must have distinct machine-precision numerical values" ``

What is the trick to make it work?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
mantissa = 24;
targetValue = 5;
SF = StringForm;
f[x_?NumericQ] := Nest[6  Cos[#] &, x, 10];
interval = 
  Interval@SetPrecision[targetValue, Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]]];
Plot[f[x], {x}~Join~MinMax@interval, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 PlotLabel -> SF["`` bit around ``", mantissa, targetValue] ]
```

Increasing the interval makes it work, but I need the original smaller interval

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
mantissa = 16;
targetValue = 5;
SF = StringForm;
f[x_?NumericQ] := Nest[6   Cos[#] &, x, 8];
interval = 
  Interval@SetPrecision[targetValue, Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]]];
Plot[f[x], {x}~Join~MinMax@interval, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 PlotLabel -> SF["`` bit around ``", mantissa, targetValue]]
```

[image]

(fix for mantissa=24 but fails for mantissa=53)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
wp = 100;
iters = 20;
mantissa = 24;
targetValue = 5;
SF = StringForm;
f[x_?NumericQ, iters_] := Nest[6    Cos[#] &, x, iters];
interval = 
  Interval@SetPrecision[targetValue, Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]]];
minmax = SetPrecision[interval[[1]], wp];
iterList = {5, 12, 13, 14};
Plot @@ {f[x, #] & /@ iterList, {x}~Join~minmax, 
  WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   SF["Values within an ulp for ``", TraditionalForm[x == 6  Cos[x]]],
   PlotLegends -> (SF["`` iterations", #] & /@ iterList)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of the things I've done, when demonstrating floating-point numbers in numerical analysis class. You could also use `ListPlot` after generating the data with `Table`. In `Table` you can scale the x coordinates to be something "reasonable." In this case, reasonable means something that the gpu, which operates with machine precision and not arbitrary precision, can handle gracefully. You can also iterate through consecutive floating-point numbers, if desired. In any case, if you do not want to do any of that, here's an adaptation of what I would do with `Plot`: Translate the center of the problem to $x=0$, where the floating-point format can scale down to 10^-308 if necessary. Then make the ticks indicate the offset from the center. In the OP's case, the center is `5`.

```
mantissa = 53;
targetValue = 5;
SF = StringForm;
f[x_?NumericQ] := Nest[6   Cos[#] &, x, 28];
interval = 
  Interval@SetPrecision[targetValue, Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]]];
exp = First@
    Log2@Differences@SetPrecision[MinMax@interval, Infinity] - 3;
Plot[f[x + 5]
 , {x}~Join~(MinMax@interval - 5.)
 , WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotPoints -> 100,
 Ticks -> {Table[{k*2.^exp, k}, {k, -5, 5}], Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {Row[{"\[Times] ", 2^Row[{exp}]}], None}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-4.5*2^exp, -6.5}, GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  SF["\[PlusMinus]`` bit around ``", mantissa, targetValue]]
```

[image]

`exp` doesn't seem to need to be rounded, but you could do it if want to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
mantissa = 24;
targetValue = 5;
SF = StringForm;
f[x_?NumericQ] := NestList[6 Cos[#] &, x, 10];

interval = (targetValue + {-10^(-# + 1), 10^(-# + 1)}) &@
   Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]];

Plot[f[x], {x}~Join~MinMax@interval, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 PlotLabel -> SF["`` bit around ``", mantissa, targetValue]]
```

---

[image]

With `mantissa = 23`.

[image]

Comment: ok, it looks the the issue is that Interval object has endpoints with low precision, so precision must be set for those

Comment: Why doing it so cumbersome when you can use exact values for plotting interval?

Comment: To easily switch between float16, float32, float64, this way I don't have to do mantissa math each time to figure out correct interval inside of an [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place). This is the motivating [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/43857/18786)

Comment: There is probably some precision limitations how narrow plotting interval can be. For mantissa `53` the interval is about `10^(-10)` wide. So I am not sure want you hope for to see on such narrow interval? Even simpler example `Plot[x, {x, 1, 1 + 10^-13}]`.

Comment: This interval is narrow w.r.t. $MachinePrecision, for for high working precision it's quite wide

Comment: OK, that Sine example makes it look like it's a bug in Mathematica, it appears some internal calculations ignore `WorkingPrecision` option, another bug along these lines was described in Michael E2's [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/287009/217)

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: So it is limitation of `Plot`, the simple example in the previous comment is all with exact numbers yet `Plot` is unable to plot it. You have to code your own plot function for such narrow intervals.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Increase the precision of `interval`

```
Manipulate[
 targetValue = 5;
 SF = StringForm;
 f[x_?NumericQ] := NestList[6   Cos[#] &, x, 10];
 interval = Interval@SetPrecision[targetValue, Floor[mantissa*Log[10, 2]]];
 Column[{
   StringForm["precision of interval is ``", Precision[interval]],
   Plot[f[x], {x}~Join~MinMax@SetPrecision[interval, 15],
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    MaxRecursion -> 5,
    PlotLabel -> SF["`` bit around ``", mantissa, targetValue],
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{mantissa, 24}, 17, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {mantissa}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! BTW, this fails for mantissa$=53$ which is the range of float64 ulp, any fix for that?

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: That is why you have to use exact values, my code works also with `mantissa =53`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I just tried copying your code verbatin and changing `mantissa=53` and it gives `SystemException` red overlay on graph (Mathematica 14.0)

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: No, for me it works.

Comment: @azerbajdzan here's what it looks like if I try to run it on Wolfram Cloud for matissa=53. It plots some standalone points instead of curve -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/8f7ea5ae-891e-4dfd-aabe-16ed631edce6 . What is the image that you are getting?